# Detecting changes in mouse sensitivity

Tags: windows-7, monitoring, mouse

I am looking for a program working on Microsoft Windows 7 that can detect and give an alert or log whenever the mouse sensitivity is changed.

Answer (score 3):

This can be accomplished easily through AutoIt, here's a script I created,

```
#include <MsgBoxConstants.au3>
#include <FileConstants.au3>
#include <WinAPIFiles.au3>

;Open/Create log.txt file
$file = FileOpen("log.txt", 1)

;Check to see if it could be opened/created ok
If $file = -1 Then
    MsgBox(0, "Error", "Unable to open/create file.")
    Exit
EndIf

Func detectChanges()
    ;Get Mouse position
    $aPos = MouseGetPos();
    $bPos = MouseGetPos();
    ;See if the mouse position has changed (0 and 1 for x and y)
    While $bPos[0] = $aPos[0] Or $bPos[1] = $aPos[1]
        ;Keep getting new mouse position
        $bPos = MouseGetPos();
    WEnd
    ;Return new position
    Return MouseGetPos();
EndFunc   ;==>detectChanges

;Go on forever
While 1
    $position = detectChanges();
    writeToTextFile($position)
    alertBox($position);
WEnd

Func writeToTextFile($position)
    $time = "Sec: " & @SEC & " Min: " & @MIN & " Hour: " & @HOUR & " Day: " & @MDAY & " Month: " & @MON & " Year: " & @YEAR;
    $write = $time & " | X:" & $position[0] & " Y:" & $position[1] & @CRLF;
    FileWrite($file, $write)
EndFunc   ;==>writeToTextFile

Func alertBox($position)
    MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Alert: Mousemovement", "Mouse x, y: " & $position[0] & ", " & $position[1])
EndFunc   ;==>alertBox
```

You can download the compiled version [Here](http://www.filedropper.com/detectmousemovement). You can turn on and off logs and alerts by commenting out (;) the functions. You may want to add some sort of a delay (Sleep(5000) ;<= sleeps for 5 seconds) every time detectChanges() runs or else the log file could get quite large. If you have any questions, ask away:)